# Splitting `File` and `directory name with space' via shell script

Tags: shell-script, cat

I've got a file called `Files.txt` having following content:

```
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/main.m
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/AppDelegate.h
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/AppDelegate.m
```

I am pulling file and directory names as following and passing them to another process.

```
files=$(cat Files.txt)

for item in $files ; do    
  dn=$(dirname $item)

  printf $item
  printf "\n"
  printf $dn
  printf "\n\n"

  # passing to another process
done
```

However, this is getting me this:

```
TestApp/Resources/Supporting
TestApp/Resources

Files/main.m
Files

TestApp/Resources/Supporting
TestApp/Resources

Files/AppDelegate.h
Files

TestApp/Resources/Supporting
TestApp/Resources

Files/AppDelegate.m
Files
```

What I need is this:

```
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/main.m
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files

TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/AppDelegate.h
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files

TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/AppDelegate.m
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files
```

I tried prefixing space with `\` in `Files.txt` as:

```
TestApp/Resources/Supporting\ Files/main.m
```

and with `%20` as:

```
TestApp/Resources/Supporting%20Files/main.m
```

with no luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `for` loops iterate over **words** not lines
2. always quote your `"$variables"` (unless you know exactly when not to)

```
while read -r item ; do    
  dn=$(dirname "$item")

  printf "%s\n" "$item"
  printf "%s\n" "$dn"

  # pass "$item" and "$dn" to another process
done < Files.txt
```

Comment: Thanks but it seem to complain at the last line: `dofiles.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
dofiles.sh: line 9: `  done < Files.txt'`

Comment: Oops, missed the semicolon before "do"

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the field separator:

```
OIFS=$IFS  
IFS=$'\n'

files=$(cat Files.txt)

for item in $files ; do    
  dn=$(dirname $item)
  printf $item
  printf "\n"
  printf $dn
  printf "\n\n"

  # passing to another process
done

IFS=$OIFS
```

Output:

```
[me@localhost test]$ ./test.sh 
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/main.m
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files

TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/AppDelegate.h
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files

TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files/AppDelegate.m
TestApp/Resources/Supporting Files
```

Explanation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator

The `$IFS` variable defines how input is split into tokens, and the default is space, tab, and newline.  Since you want to split only on newlines, the `$IFS` variable needs to be temporarily changed.

Comment: +1 - This works too. I picked the first answer, but up voted you - thanks!